# SQL Join tables based on Id in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, join

I need to pull all the policies' cols for a claiment's ID with a JOIN stored Procedure.

pseudocode : select * from policies(tbl) where parties.id = policy.policyNumber.

Here's what I have so far...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetPolicyForClaimentByPolicyIdNumber]
(
    @IdNumber varchar(255) = null
)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT *
    FROM [BinderCurrent].[Policy]
    LEFT JOIN [BinderCurrent].[Policy] ON ([BinderCurrent].[Parties].Id = [BinderCurrent].[PolicyRoles].PolicyId)
    WHERE   [BinderCurrent].[PolicyRoles].PolicyRoleTypeId = 40
    AND (@IdNumber IS NULL OR [BinderCurrent].[Parties].IdNumber LIKE ''+@IdNumber+'%') 
    ORDER BY Id DESC

END
```

Comment: "I need" isn't a question. What are you asking here? Why isn't what you have already not working?

Comment: You reference `[BinderCurrent].[PolicyRoles]` in your `WHERE`, but it isn't defined in your `FROM`. Also 3+ part naming for columns is to be deprecated and removed. It's recommended you use aliases and qualify your columns with those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter with `ON` clause :

```
SELECT *
FROM [BinderCurrent].[Policy] LEFT JOIN 
     [BinderCurrent].[Policy] 
     ON ([BinderCurrent].[Parties].Id = [BinderCurrent].[PolicyRoles].PolicyId AND
         [BinderCurrent].[PolicyRoles].PolicyRoleTypeId = 40
WHERE (@IdNumber IS NULL OR [BinderCurrent].[Parties].IdNumber LIKE ''+@IdNumber+'%')
ORDER BY Id DESC;
```

Note : Table `[BinderCurrent].[PolicyRoles]` should also appeared with `JOIN`s. This assumes that is part of your query.